# Displaying attribute field value in TextElement gives AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, search, attributeerror

I am new in Python scripting. I have a geodatabase with layer `Test` and this layer has field `Name` and Text element on layout named `TEname`. I am trying to show selected feature attribute `Name` value in Text element, but I could not do it.  I can print the value for selected feature, but can't show it in Text element.

Here is the code I use:

```
import arcpy


mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
TEname = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT","Name")[0]

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Test","name")
     print row
```

...
(u'Land plot 1',)

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Test","name"):
    TEname.text = row
```

...

> > > TEname.text = row

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py", line 89, in _set
    return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
RuntimeError: TextElementObject: Error in setting text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `TEname` to a list of text element objects when you do this:

```
TEname = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT","Name")
```

To get a single text element object from that list use an index of 0 on that list:

```
TEname = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT","Name")[0]
```